# Issue with Axis2 WebService running on Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I have a web service application that I deployed successfully on Apache Tomcat using Eclipse IDE. However after a restart to my computer is not working any more. While trying to the list of services I get the following.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /ScWS/services/listServices
type Status report
message /ScWS/services/listServices
description The requested resource (/ScWS/services/listServices) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.11
```

When Tomcat is loading I see the following in the console logs:

```
Mar 19, 2011 10:46:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
Mar 19, 2011 10:47:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 19, 2011 10:47:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 19, 2011 10:47:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 10342 ms
Mar 19, 2011 10:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 19, 2011 10:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.11
Mar 19, 2011 10:47:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ScWS.xml from /home/blueprint/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/conf/Catalina/localhost
Mar 19, 2011 10:47:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ScWS' did not find a matching property.
Mar 19, 2011 10:47:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 19, 2011 10:47:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 19, 2011 10:47:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5593 ms
```

Anyone have any ideas what might be the Issue?

Comment: have you tried clean up from scratch and publish to tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted everything about Tomcat and installed again and everything was up and running.